# capture the error message of ssh command

Tags: shell

I am trying to capture the error message when executing the ssh command.
Below is the excerpt of my code:

```
     #       errMsg=`ssh build@$h 'mkdir -p $rmtRepo' 2>&1`
             sh build@$h "mkdir -p $rmtRepo"
if [[ -n $errMsg ]]; then
                    echo "Unable to make the ssh connection for the host $h: $errMsg"
                fi
```

When using the commented line, error message is echoed but the mkdir command if there is no error fails to execute with the below error.  Why the mkdir command is failing? If I do not have the code to capture the error message, mkdir command gets executed successfully. Please suggest how can I execute the make command if no error condition and capture the error if any at the same time?
mkdir: missing operand
Try `mkdir --help' for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Let say for example you got error in making directory.

You can check it by looking if the directory exists or not.

```
if [ ! -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
  # you can echo some error message here
  exit 1 #to terminate execution of code
fi
```

The point here is that, if you have error on the above code, you cannot get the error message on the following code because it will automatically terminated once got some early error.